# Retrofit app crashes when connecting to the API

Tags: java, android, retrofit

So I'm making an app that connect to a recipe api that has the following data:

```
{"count": 30, "recipes": 
[{"publisher": "Simply Recipes", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/36251", "title": "Easy Brazilian Cheese Bread", "source_url": "http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/easy_brazilian_cheese_bread/", "recipe_id": "36251", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/braziliancheesebreada300x200ffd79a7b.jpg", "social_rank": 100.0, "publisher_url": "http://simplyrecipes.com"}, 
{"publisher": "All Recipes", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/32745", "title": "To Die For Blueberry Muffins", "source_url": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/To-Die-For-Blueberry-Muffins/Detail.aspx", "recipe_id": "32745", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/6629086e7e.jpg", "social_rank": 100.0, "publisher_url": "http://allrecipes.com"}, 
{"publisher": "All Recipes", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/3068", "title": "Basic Crepes", "source_url": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Basic-Crepes/Detail.aspx", "recipe_id": "3068", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/4005704623.jpg", "social_rank": 100.0, "publisher_url": "http://allrecipes.com"}, 
{"publisher": "The Pioneer Woman", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/fbc7af", "title": "The Best Chocolate Sheet Cake. Ever.", "source_url": "http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2007/06/the_best_chocol/", "recipe_id": "fbc7af", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/388604527_5e6812454fc6f7.jpg", "social_rank": 100.0, "publisher_url": "http://thepioneerwoman.com"}, 
{"publisher": "All Recipes", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/33124", "title": "Tres Leches Cake", "source_url": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Tres-Leches-Milk-Cake/Detail.aspx", "recipe_id": "33124", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/384988ad12.jpg", "social_rank": 99.99999999999999, "publisher_url": "http://allrecipes.com"}, 
{"publisher": "All Recipes", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/10467", "title": "Creamy Rice Pudding", "source_url": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Creamy-Rice-Pudding/Detail.aspx", "recipe_id": "10467", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/1086813697.jpg", "social_rank": 99.99999999999999, "publisher_url": "http://allrecipes.com"}, 
{"publisher": "Closet Cooking", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35499", "title": "Pumpkin Pie French Toast", "source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2009/11/pumpkin-pie-french-toast.html", "recipe_id": "35499", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/PumpkinPieFrenchToast15002845c7fe.jpg", "social_rank": 99.99999999999997, "publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com"}, 
{"publisher": "Two Peas and Their Pod", "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/54363", "title": "Chocolate Sheet Cake with Peanut Butter Frosting", "source_url": "http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com/chocolate-sheet-cake-with-peanut-butter-frosting/", "recipe_id": "54363", "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/chocolatesheetcakewithpeanutbutterfrosting3a2ac.jpg", "social_rank": 99.99999999999997, "publisher_url": "http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com"}]
```

Here are the models:

```
package com.example.mobilniproekt.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Recipe {

@SerializedName("publisher")
private String publisher;

@SerializedName("f2f_url")
private String f2f_url;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("source_url")
private String source_url;

@SerializedName("recipe_id")
private String recipe_id;

@SerializedName("image_url")
private String image_url;

@SerializedName("social_rank")
private Float social_rank;

@SerializedName("publisher_url")
private String publisher_url;

public Recipe(String publisher, String f2f_url, String title, String source_url, String recipe_id, String image_url, Float social_rank, String publisher_url) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.f2f_url = f2f_url;
    this.title = title;
    this.source_url = source_url;
    this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.social_rank = social_rank;
    this.publisher_url = publisher_url;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public String getF2f_url() {
    return f2f_url;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getSource_url() {
    return source_url;
}

public String getRecipe_id() {
    return recipe_id;
}

public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}

public Float getSocial_rank() {
    return social_rank;
}

public String getPublisher_url() {
    return publisher_url;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public void setF2f_url(String f2f_url) {
    this.f2f_url = f2f_url;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setSource_url(String source_url) {
    this.source_url = source_url;
}

public void setRecipe_id(String recipe_id) {
    this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
}

public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}

public void setSocial_rank(Float social_rank) {
    this.social_rank = social_rank;
}

public void setPublisher_url(String publisher_url) {
    this.publisher_url = publisher_url;
}
}


package com.example.mobilniproekt.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;
```

The second model:

```
public class Recipes {

@SerializedName("count")
private Integer count;

@SerializedName("recipes")
private List<Recipe> recipeList;

public Recipes(Integer count, List<Recipe> recipeList) {
    this.count = count;
    this.recipeList = recipeList;
}

public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

public List<Recipe> getRecipeList() {
    return recipeList;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void setRecipeList(List<Recipe> recipeList) {
    this.recipeList = recipeList;
}
}
```

The retrofit client:

```
package com.example.mobilniproekt.retrofit;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClientInstance {

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.food2fork.com";

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}


}
```

And the Interface:

```
package com.example.mobilniproekt.retrofit;

import com.example.mobilniproekt.model.Recipes;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface GetDataService {

@GET("/api/search?key=API_KEY&q=milk,eggs")
Call<Recipes> getRecipes();

}
```

And finally the main implementation:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressDialog progressDoalog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDoalog.setMessage("Loading....");
    progressDoalog.show();

    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
    Call<Recipes> call = service.getRecipes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Recipes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Recipes> call, Response<Recipes> response) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            TextView textViewTest=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
            textViewTest.setText(response.body().getRecipeList().get(10).getTitle());
            Log.d(response.body().getRecipeList().get(10).getTitle(), response.body().getRecipeList().get(10).getPublisher());
            //generateDataList(response.body().getRecipeList());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Recipes> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

However when I run the app on my phone the app immediately crashes. I thought the error was in the model when I declared a Float social_rank and changed it to double however that didn't help so I switched back to float.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please add the log from the Logcat to identify the error or reason for the crash. Always add log files as it helps in quickly identifying the problem for others and you'll get quicker responses.

Comment: Okay. How do I do that? Just to mention that I can only debug this on my phone not on an emulator because my laptop is too weak and it crashes.

Comment: Another thing to just bring up; have you declared 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

In your manifest? 

I've made that mistake a number of times :D

Comment: Yes I have that's not the problem.

Comment: Not running an emulator is not a problem. You can connect your mobile device to your computer via usb and run the app by selecting the connected mobile device when prompted by Android Studio to select an emulator or device. Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

Comment: Make sure your response contains at least 11 items of type `Recipe` to successfully call `response.body().getRecipeList().get(10)` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can occur.

Comment: Yes It contains 30 results. I just posted less in order to make the post shorter.

Comment: Share the crash log!

Comment: Make sure you're not making the network request on the main thread, otherwise it will throw an exception.